# Storybook 6.0.26 react and hashrouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, storybook

We have been using storybook with hashrouter to navigate in application. We have story of which contains router navigation via hashrouter. In Storybook 5 hashrouter worked fine, but some how when refreshing page from browser storybook removes #/ routes. Storybook version 5 didn't do that. Is there any work around or some configs for this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"



export default {
    title: 'HashRouter'
};


export const RouterStories = () => {

    return (
        <HashRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                    demo 1
                </Route>
                <Route path="/demo2" exact>
                    demo 2
                </Route>
                <Route path="/demo3" exact>
                    demo 3
                </Route>
            </Switch>
            
        </HashRouter>
    )
}
```

example url when refreshing:

```
http://localhost:9009/iframe.html?id=hashrouter--router-stories&viewMode=story#/demo2
```

When you hit the browser refresh with that url, it renders back to

```
http://localhost:9009/iframe.html?id=hashrouter--router-stories&viewMode=story
```

Comment: Looks like the issue was in our configurations. Fixed

Comment: Can you provide what was wrong with the configuration?

Comment: Hmm, dont remember it anymore. try delete node_modules and reinstall